# How to check and free up disk space in CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, disk-space-utilization

I have a**160 GB** VPS with pre-installed CentOS 7 and Webuzo. Using the `du -sh` command in the **www** dir I noticed that my sites consume barely **60GB**, while the total used space is **120 GB**.

Which means my CentOS installation is using **60 GB** of space. I read somewhere that 20 GB is enough to install CentOS, so the question is exactly how do I find out what's eating up all space? The Webuzo dir itself in /usr/ is less than 1 GB.

Being a Windows user, I'm not very fond of Unix commands, so any help will be appreciated... I need to free up as much space as possible, thanks. I have full root access via SSH and WinSCP.

Comment: https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu is a nice tool to help you discover where your system is consuming the most disk space. - Fairly typical are log files that get too big or kept too long or even indefinitely btw

Answer (score 1):

you can use `du` in `/`

```
cd /
du -skh * |sort -h
```

This will sort the biggest directories at the bottom. thne navigate into them and execute the `du` again until you are satisfied with your findings.